# Understanding the match operator

Tags: mule, dataweave

Hi I am confused about the usage of the match operator. I have come across a snippet of code that looks nothing like the explanation on the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#match

```
%function testMatch(key)
    (key match {
        x when x is :null -> false,
        x when x == "A" -> true, 
        x when x == "B" -> false, 
        x when x == "J" -> true, 
        x when x == "K" -> false, 
        x when x == "L" -> true, 
        default -> false
    })
```

Please help understand the meaning of this syntax for match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! The `match` keyword serves two purposes in DataWeave, and it depends on its placement. Match is either used for regex, or pattern matching.

---

#### `match` for Regex

If `match` has a string on the left-hand side (lhs) and a regex on the rhs, it will operate according to the following [docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#match). Basically, it's doing regex matching:

> Match returns an array that contains the entire matching expression, followed by all of the capture groups that match the provided regex.

---

#### `match` for Pattern Matching

If `match` has anything that evaluates to a value (i.e., does not evaluate to a function) on the lhs and an open bracket on the rhs, `match` is now doing pattern matching. You can find that docs for that [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-language-introduction#pattern-matching). I cover this pretty extensively in the talk I did, you can find the slides for that [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GMlTgRL5E5rR7GKGIZlwe-ugrPLigU5v?usp=sharing).

For the example you provided (nice formatting, btw):

```
%function testMatch(key)
    (key match {
        x when x is :null -> false,
        x when x == "A" -> true, 
        x when x == "B" -> false, 
        x when x == "J" -> true, 
        x when x == "K" -> false, 
        x when x == "L" -> true, 
        default -> false
    })
```

`match` is checking if its input, `x`, is `null`, A, B, J, K, or L. If it matches any of those, DW will evaluate what's on the rhs of the arrow, and return immediately. If nothing matches, it will return what is on the rhs of the arrow for `default`.

Comment: Ah it's just a straightforward application of syntax directly from documentation.!
I had understood the result having some knowledge about switch case but imagined that may be there is some combination of different concepts involved like lambda... etc (documentation mentions lambda can be used inside operators).

Comment: Yeah, but it can be a little difficult to find the difference if you don't already know about the pattern matching part :) `match` for pattern matching is pretty flexible in DW, so you could use labmdas as expressions as well.